# How to change yum's default downloader

Tags: package-management, yum, curl

By default `yum` uses `curl` to download packages from internet repositories.

I want use `axel` instead of `curl` to download packages: is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Yum calls curl directly (I believe through the library, not the executable). In any case, the update/install speed won't get better. If you are on Fedora, Fedora 18 has dnf as an experimental alternative to yum, it is *much* faster in resolving dependencies, and more accurate too. But it still has rather rough edges, and the tools around yum haven't been migrated. Both can be used (almost) interchangeably, in any case.

Comment: Wow, I didn't hear any thing about DNF, it's in test mode! 
thanks for introduce!